# BNF grammar using loop statements

Tags: c

Write a simple BNF grammar for a subset of C that supports multiple statements including assignment, if-else, and while statements without block statements.  Use meaningful names for your nonterminals (vs. cryptic letters).  Assume variables are represented by single letters and are integers.  Assume that the standard precedence rules apply for the operators *, /, +, -, and parentheses.  Make sure to include relational operators (==, !=, <, >, >=, and <=).    The following is a valid program for your grammar:

```
 a = -35;while (b > a);a = a + b;if (a >= 10);c = a;else c = b;
```

Can you expand your BNF to properly handle a C block statement as part of a while or if or else?  Revise your productions to support:
    while (b > a)
    a = a + b;
    printf(“in loop”);

using the above grammar I came up with

```
<statement> ::=  a=-35
<while> ::= while (b>a)
<assign>::= a = a + b;
<if>::= if (a >= 10) 
<assign> ::= c=a;
<else> 
<assign> ::= c = b;

<while>::= while (b>a)
<assign>:= a = a + b;
<statement>::= printf ("in loop");
```

Is this a valid bnf grammar ?

Comment: @scravy Obviously this is homework (who else but a teacher would be interested in "a subset of C BNF grammar"?). The issue is not if it is homework or not (why should homework be different of a work assignment) but if the poster is doing a real effort to resolve the problem himself or if he only wants someone to dump the code. So I mostly answer with some clues in the right direction (unless it is a very specific issue).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. What you are writting are more examples than a grammar. A grammar explains how to produce all the valid constructs of the language.

For example

```
 <while> ::= while <expression> <block>
```

Then, you define `<expression>` in a way that allows to write *any* expression in the language, and `<block>` as a block of statements (a simple statement or several statement grouped by brackets).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form